# extract pdf in xml

Tags: php, xml, laravel, pdf

I have an xml that returns a pdf in sting.
But I want to convert it to file.
How i can do it in `php`? Or is there any library in laravel?

> This is the xml:

```
<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>
<OutputImage>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</OutputImage>
```

Comment: You can use [simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml) to load XML file, then (probably) [base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode) to get the data and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) to save the data to a file.

Comment: Extract the string from `OutputImage` and then just `file_put_contents('foo.pdf', base64_decode($str));`

Comment: Try base64 decoding the `OutputImage` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package, [xml-to-array](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array) to convert it, then do something like this:

```
$xml = '<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>
<OutputImage>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</OutputImage';

$array = \Mtownsend\XmlToArray\XmlToArray::convert($xml);

file_put_contents('filename.pdf', base64_decode($array['OutputImage']));
```